# Oracle OR database: why does ref() function get object instead of OID?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, ref, object-relational-model

I'm using Oracle (11g) and SQL Developer tool (v. 4.1.3). I have an Object-Relational Database.

I do this:

```
CREATE TYPE emp_person_typ AS OBJECT (
    name VARCHAR2(30), 
    manager REF emp_person_typ ); 
/
CREATE TABLE emp_person_obj_table OF emp_person_typ; 
INSERT INTO emp_person_obj_table 
    SELECT emp_person_typ ('Bob Jones', REF(e)) 
    FROM emp_person_obj_table e 
   WHERE e.name = 'John Smith';

select * from emp_person_obj_table e;
```

And I get:

```
NAME          MANAGER                                       
---------- --------------------------------------------------
John Smith                                                  
Bob Jones     EMP_PERSON_TYP('John Smith', NULL)
```

However, in the `manager` column, instead of the object `(EMP_PERSON_TYP())` I should get the `OID`.

I guess that perhaps it is an issue of configuration, perhaps I should configure SQL Developer in a specific way, but I don't know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure that is configurable. There's an 'advanced' preference for showing the structure in grid view, but that doesn't show OID if it's off, and doesn't affect the worksheet. Version 4.2.0 does show the OID in the worksheet though, so is upgrading an option?

Comment: It worked!! With the 4.2.0 version. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Also, as [this is an example from the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28371/adobjint.htm#CIHCBCIC), which generally assumes you're using SQL\*Plus, does it actually matter? You'd generally dereference anyway, to get the manager's name for instance (as shown in later examples).

Comment: Yes, absolutelly, it matters. From the oracle documetation: _"REF takes as its argument a correlation variable (table alias) associated with a row of an object table or an object view. **A REF value is returned** for the object instance that is bound to the variable or row."_ I study the documetation, I learn it, so I hope to find that behaviour, regardless of which specific tool I use.

Comment: A REF is being returned; the client is interpreting/displaying it differently. If you want to see the OID that's fine, it just doesn't seem particularly useful to me, but it's not my scenario *8-)